# multiple if and then function in excel 2010

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to write a nested function in Excel 2010.
All the tips out there don’t seem to cover what I am looking to do which is:

```
If A2=B2 And G2=TBS1401 And J1=OA or O8, Then I2=OA
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
IF(AND(A2=B2, G2=TBS1401, OR(J1=OA,J1=08)), I2=0A)
```